# Android Studio Gradle task for a specific build variant

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

I've been wrestling with this all day. So, I currently use the task in my build.gradle to compile the debug NDK code in my project:

```
task buildNative(type: Exec, description: 'Compile JNI source via NDK') {
def ndkDir = android.ndkDirectory
commandLine "$ndkDir/ndk-build",
        '-C', file('src/main/jni').absolutePath, // Change src/main/jni the relative path to your jni source
        '-j', Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors(),
        'NDK_APPLICATION_MK=Application.mk',
        'all',
        'NDK_DEBUG=1'}
```

All I need to do is have a different command line for the **release** build variant, but all my attempts seem to always compile both tasks.

Is it possible to have a task only for release build? Or to modify the command line dynamically with some conditional statement?

Answer (score 0):

You can execute this task for specific flavour/variant like this:

```
buildNativeFlavourVariant
```

for example:

```
buildNativeProdRelease
```

Comment: yes, I have defined two tasks one for release and one for debug. But how is it possible to run only one depending on variant?